# mobile website click to text

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile site and I want my users to be able to click a button and enter a number and be able to send a text message from the mobile site. Its not an application, its just a site. Is it possible. If so , how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.

If you know the provider of the phone number (ask the customer for it),
You can email that number like 2125555555@verizon.net (google for the proper emails to all the common providers).

Or you can sign up for a texting service and send them the SMS through an API.

This generally isn't  free.

Comment: sorry if confusing but my question was more on front end side. Like how to code the actual html so the text message box comes up

Comment: I think your question was answered by @boruch, if you're asking a different question please post another or edit this question http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Are you looking for the frontend <input> tag?
Or for the backend on how to process the input?

Comment: something like <form action="text.php"><input type="text" name="chat"> ?